# Script doesn't work when called from cron

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, cron, rsync

I have the following script that works fine when called from the command line:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u root -ppassword redmine > /home/administrateur/backup/backup_$(date+%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql
find /home/administrateur/backup/* -mtime +15 -exec rm {} \;
rsync -e 'ssh -p 22' -avzp /home/administrateur/backup is-uber-1:/home/administrateur/backup
```

But this script omits the rsync line when called from cron.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: You sure it works fine? `$(date+%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S)` doesn't have a space in it.

Comment: Yes I assure you it works fine when called from the command line, the dump file gets created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to run your script as `administrateur`. You can use `sudo` for it:

```
/usr/bin/sudo -H -u administrateur -- /bin/sh /path/to/your/script.sh
```